# Rails form for nested object w/ user inputed key values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, simple-form, erb

I have a model for Experiment and the schema looks like this:

```
create_table "experiments", id: :serial, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "state"
    t.jsonb "experiment_conditions"
end
```

As you can see in the schema, experiment_conditions is type jsonb. I want the user to be able to name the key whatever they want and give it a number (percentage of 100).

For example: `{"control": 10, "variant": 90}` or `{"control": 50, "other": 50}`

The issue I am having is with the form in the view file. 
I know that I need it to follow this pattern:

```
<%= form.text_field_tag "experiment[experiment_conditions][name_of_key]", [experiment_value] %>
```

But I can't figure out a way to allow the user to enter both the key and value of a nested object in a rails form. I've considered using the cocoon gem, but from the looks of it, that gem only works with ActiveRecord associated models. Anyhow, thank you in advance!

Note: I'm hoping to find a solution without using javascript

Comment: Does the user have to be able to create several of these keys at once?

Comment: Yes. They need to have at least 2 variants ["Control", "Variant"] or ["Control", "a", "b"]

Comment: Are you really that married to the idea of a JSON column? This sounds like something you could do by adding a separate experiment_conditions table with a has_many association and `accepts_nested_attributes_for :experiment_conditions`

Comment: @max I was thinking the same thing. It was actually the existing data structure on something I was working on. Might have no choice but to break it up into separate tables

Comment: Breaking it up on the whole is probably positive as it gives you some sort of schema.